# Laravel Mix add dependencies

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, simplemde

I want use [sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor) in Laravel Mix compiling.

I have add this line in **app.scss**:

> @import "node_modules/simplemde/dist/simplemde.min.css";

and this line in **app.js**:

> window.SimpleMDE = require('simplemde');

I want compiling this plugin in my project...

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: My error: http://imgur.com/a/rtvSE

Comment: What version of Laravel mix did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* in webpack.mix.js file add following lines at the end  */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')

   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

After adding Run below command in terminal

1. `npm run dev` 
   (or)
2. `npm run watch`